# Troubleshooting Netflow Visibility Issue in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, cisco, netflow

good time to you.

I have a Cisco 2960 switch and I want to receive netflow data from this switch in Kibana so that I can design a dashboard for the received netflow. I was able to do this easily in GrayLog, but in Kibana, although netflow is being sent to Kibana, it is not visible in the Analytics section under the Discovery tab. If you have any experience in this matter, please guide me. Thank you.

I tried using Filebeat, Logstash, and CiscoLog in the Integrations section of Kibana to visualize netflow data in the Discovery tab. However, it did not work.